# Finding the URL to export data to csv

Tags: python, html

I am using a website called baseballsavant.com to download Major League Baseball data in Python. Baseball Savant provides a user-friendly API to query data in individual plays of pretty much any Major League Baseball game since 2008 and has an option to export the results of the user's query to a CSV file.

The following URL gives the results of a simple query:

```
https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/statcast_search?hfPT=&hfAB=&hfBBT=&hfPR=&hfZ=&stadium=&hfBBL=&hfNewZones=&hfGT=R%7C&hfC=&hfSea=2019%7C&hfSit=&player_type=pitcher&hfOuts=&opponent=&pitcher_throws=&batter_stands=&hfSA=&game_date_gt=&game_date_lt=&hfInfield=&team=&position=&hfOutfield=&hfRO=&home_road=&hfFlag=&hfPull=&pitchers_lookup%5B%5D=434378&metric_1=&hfInn=&min_pitches=0&min_results=0&group_by=name&sort_col=pitches&player_event_sort=h_launch_speed&sort_order=desc&min_pas=0#results
```

A python library that I use called **baseball_scraper** can query the Baseball Savant database through Python. Looking at the source code, I found that by modifying the URL from above, someone can automatically download the data in CSV form. The difference is that **/csv** and **&type=details&** are added to the URL, while **#results** is removed. Here is the URL to download the data as a CSV file (note: following this link should download a file to your hard drive):

```
https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/statcast_search/csv?hfPT=&hfAB=&hfBBT=&hfPR=&hfZ=&stadium=&hfBBL=&hfNewZones=&hfGT=R%7C&hfC=&hfSea=2019%7C&hfSit=&player_type=pitcher&hfOuts=&opponent=&pitcher_throws=&batter_stands=&hfSA=&game_date_gt=&game_date_lt=&hfInfield=&team=&position=&hfOutfield=&hfRO=&home_road=&hfFlag=&hfPull=&pitchers_lookup%5B%5D=434378&metric_1=&hfInn=&min_pitches=0&min_results=0&group_by=name&sort_col=pitches&player_event_sort=h_launch_speed&sort_order=desc&min_pas=0&type=details&
```

I'm unfamiliar with web design and would like to be able to replicate this technique on other websites that have an option to export data to CSV files. However, looking at the source code of the first URL, I can't understand how one would be able to tell that adding **/csv** and **&type=details&** to the URL would trigger the CSV download. Is there something specific in the source code that I should be looking for that tells how to export to CSV automatically?

Comment: This isnt necessarily difficult, but we need to see your attempt at doing this here.  I would say that you should consider implementing this slowly and when you get it printing what you want in the interpreter, then we could focus on the second part, downloading it as a file.

Comment: There's a few ways you can go about doing something like this, but the first thing to note about the #results being removed in the 2nd query is because in that first query, you are requesting specific data. The hashtag "#" is actually called a URL fragment and it basically points the browser cursor where you tell it, hence it jumping immediately to the search results on the page when you click it. Second URL can be written like that because they have a different call where either the file exists already in directory, or query is creating the file write out and needs to specify what type it is.

Comment: @Fallenreaper I hadn't actually thought to put the source code in an interpreter. I was mainly looking for search terms like "csv" and "details" in the source code, which wasn't very helpful. After putting the source code into an interpreter and clicking the "Export to CSV" button, it takes me to an error screen that says:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /statcast_search/csv was not found on this server.
```

I think this could have been how the creator of the python package knew to add "/csv" to the url, I'll try to replicate this process on other sites. Thank you for your help!